# Fragments overlap after transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

I made the LauncherActivity of the app a NavigationDrawer Activity. Then i made two test Fragments : "VibBearFragment" and "FragmentTwo"
I used this code in onNavigationItemSelected() to switch between Fragments. And i included the "VibBearFragment" in the contents of the drawer so that it is there when the app starts.

```
 Fragment fragment = new FragmentTwo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_teddy_vib:
            fragment = new VibBearFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_fragment1:
            break;
        case R.id.vibActivity:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_call_me:
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));
            startActivity(callIntent);

            break;
        default:
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();
            break;
    }
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.vibFragment, fragment).commit();
```

But the "VibBearFragment" just covers up "FragmentTwo" and they overlap.And all the buttons work when the Fragments are overlapping.The interesting part is that if I click "FragmentTwo" they overlap , but if I click "VibBearFragment" even if "FragmentTwo" was open it works properly .

This is the XML for the Fragment that gets replaced grammatically

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutSwap"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.slaven.teddybear.Drawer"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_drawer">


<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.example.slaven.teddybear.Fragments.VibBearFragment"
    android:id="@+id/vibFragment"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    tools:layout="@layout/vib_bear_fragment" />
```

I did my best to try and show you the problem. Also Button N2 (from the picture)
dissapears when activities overlap but still works.Can anyone please help ?

[image: This is the problem]

Comment: Don't use a fragment in the xml layout if you plan to include it in a transaction(like replacing it). Instead manually add it in onCreate().

Comment: @Luksprog  I am fairly new to Android could you give me a few pointers on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do transactions with static fragment(the ones defined in the xml layout). If you do plan to do transactions then manually add them.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutSwap"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.slaven.teddybear.Drawer"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_drawer">

   <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"   
      android:layout_height="match_parent"   />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your activities onCreate() method add the fragment from the layout:

```
//...onCreate()  
Fragment content = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.content);
if (savedInstance == null || content == null) {
    // add the initial fragment from the layout
    content = new VibBearFragment();
    getSupportFragmentmanager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, content).commit();
}
```

Comment: I think I understand now but why do you check this : if (savedInstance == null || content == null)  ?

Comment: @SlavenIvanov If savedInstance is null then you're dealing with a fresh start of the activity and you need to add a fragment. If savedInstance is not null the activity has been recreated and already has an instance of the fragment which will be restored automatically. I also checked content being null to make sure we will have a fragment for the content.